# VBA, Need a conditional Sum based on a change in another column

Tags: vba, excel

New to VBA. Trying to run through a list of unique id's and subtotal values related to each id.

Afterwards, that sum total needs to be displayed in a different column on the first line.

Considerations:

- As it finds a new id, the subtotal needs to start over and only subtotal the block of values related to it.
- Each subtotal needs to be displayed only once next to the first instance of the unique id in the list.
- each new sheet will have 5 k rows or more and the data will be in the same columns. Lots of data.
- The columns in my sheet are not actually physically next to each other but are in the same sheet.
- in each print the custid will change at a different row. It needs to iterate through the id's and find the change and sum the values for that custid only.
  Afterwards, that sum total needs to be displayed in a different column on the first line.

This is some basic sample data:

Totl    Subttl  CustID  Amt.

```
        123456  55.74
        123456  61.47
        223456  44.53
        223456  142.11
        223456  -142.11
        333456  44.53
        333456  52.89
        333456  118.37
        333456  354.80
        443456  6.49
        443456  44.53
        443456  162.74
```

To This:

Totl Subttl  CustID  Amt.

```
946.09      117.21  123456  55.74
                    123456  61.47
            44.53   223456  44.53
                    223456  142.11
                    223456  -142.11
            570.59  333456  44.53
                    333456  52.89
                    333456  118.37
                    333456  354.80
            213.76  443456  6.49
                    443456  44.53
                    443456  162.74
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be simpler than I first expected. This code assumes that the column of unique id numbers is ordered such that they are always grouped together and not randomly distributed throughout the sheet. (If this is not the case please say and I will include a sort option first)

**EDIT**
I updated the code to include a sort first. It also copies it onto a second sheet (Sheet2) so that you do not lose you original list of data in case something goes wrong.

**EDIT 2**
Just had a thought, If you are doing this on large data sets then you will want screen updating turned off to speed things up

```
Sub sumAndFormat()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim activeRow As Long
Dim uniqueID As Long
Dim totalSum As Currency
Dim subRow As Long
Dim subTotal As Currency

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:B12")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

lastRow = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Sheets("sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row


totalSum = 0
subTotal = 0
subRow = 1

uniqueID = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).value

For i = 1 To lastRow

    totalSum = totalSum + Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).value

    If uniqueID = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) Then
        subTotal = subTotal + Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).value
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(subRow, 2).value = subTotal
        MsgBox (subTotal)
    Else
        uniqueID = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).value
        subTotal = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).value
        subRow = i
    End If



    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3).value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).value
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 4).value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).value

Next i

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).value = totalSum

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually this is very nearly perfect for my application thank you. This is what I ended up using. Simple and effective. Thanks for the Screen updating Tidbit. Very helpful. I have about two pages of VBA code besides this and it all acts on those 5k lines, so turning of updating turned into a huge help!