# Sum with offset based on Sl No

Tags: excel, sum, offset

Sum is to be based on Sl. No field (image attached)

The formula in cells are as follows
E3 : ROUNDUP(D3,-0.1)
E4 : ROUNDUP(D4,-0.1)
E7 : ROUNDUP(SUM(D5:D7),-0.1)
E9 : ROUNDUP(SUM(D8:D9),-0.1)
E10 : ROUNDUP(D10,-0.1)

I wish the sum to be calculated in Col. E.

If there is a value in the next immediate row in Sl. No. field, then the value in Col. D is to be directly displayed after rounding off to next whole number in Col. E. Whenever “” is found below the next serial number, the values from that corresponding cell in Col D should be added till the last cell against which the next serial number is not present. The sum shall be rounded off to next whole number and displayed in Col. E (highlighted) against the last value in Col. D.

User-defined function in Col.E is desirable say sumfunctionrng(B:B, E:E)

Similar problem is mentioned in [VBA - conditional Sum column B until change of value in column A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238058/vba-conditional-sum-column-b-until-change-of-value-in-column-a)

Comment: Sooo..... what's the question?

Comment: I wish the sum to be calculated in Col. E based on Sl. no field as described above

Comment: And what have *you* tried so far?

Comment: I used formula =IF(B3<>B4,SUMIF(B:B,B3,D:D)). But, in this case i have to repeat the sl. no. flag again in the sl.no field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in E3 and fill down.

```
=IF(OR(B4<>"", ROW(B3)=MATCH(1E+99, D:D)), CEILING(SUM(D3:INDEX(D:D, MATCH(1E+99, B$1:B3))), 1), "")
```

[image]

Comment: did you test that? It does not pick up the last total.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that after posting and have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the SI No into each row and hide duplicates with conditional formatting. The following screenshot uses custom format `;;;` to make cells with duplicates appear blank.

[image]

Then you can use this formula to calculate the total on the last row of a SI No.

```
=IF(B3<>B4,SUMIF(B:B,B3,D:D),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Since Sl.No is populated using data from a different sheet, hiding may not be a desirable solution.

Comment: So, how is it populated and what is in the blank cells?