# VBA - Find Changing Conditional Values in one Column based on Consecutive Dates in another Column

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and having trouble figuring out how to make this work. I am trying to:

1. Select all `DOWNTIME_CODES` that equal 60
2. Select any `DOWNTIME_CODES` that follow a code 60 and where DATE_VALUE is consecutive after a 60. (EX. VAN HOOK 2 between the dates 9/3 and 9/12).

I have been trying to create a macro that treats `DOWNTIME_CODE` = 60 as a starting point and then looks at date to see if it is consecutive, even if the `DOWNTIME_CODE` changes to a 70, 21 or whatever. There are a few hundred `COMPLETION_NAMES` so I cannot do this manually, and need to be able to loop through all the completions. I have tried to use an `IF THEN` statement to identify a code 60 and then another `IF THEN` inside that to check if `DATE_VALUE` is consecutive, and then copy those results out of the main table, and then start searching for the next  code 60. There can be separate code 60's for one completion and it is possible to have only one

This is one of the version of the code I have worked on, it is a simplified conceptualization. I have not been able to make it very far and cannot find anything similar. This is the closest example I have found:

- [VBA - conditional Sum column B until change of value in column A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238058/vba-conditional-sum-column-b-until-change-of-value-in-column-a) and
- [VBA, Need a conditional Sum based on a change in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411046/vba-need-a-conditional-sum-based-on-a-change-in-another-column?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and here is a general idea of how I have been approaching the problem.

```
If DOWNTIME_CODE = 60 Then
    If DATE_VALUE = DATE_VALUE.Offset(-1) Then
        cell.Offset(0, 2) = CHECK
    End If
Else
    DOWNTIME_CODE = DOWNTIME_CODE + DOWNTIME_CODE.Offset(0, 1)
End If
```

Example Data:
[image: Example Data]

Any help on an approach or guidance on how to do this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for taking the time to read my post!

Comment: When looking at highlighted cells only in your sample data, why is the 2nd `VAN HOOK 2` yellow and not green? It is part of a consecutive run of dates (6/1 & 6/2). This seems inconsistent since the next green portion has the first date of the run green. Or am I missing something

Comment: @urdearboy I’m sorry, that is a mistake on my part. They are part of the same run.

Comment: You should fix that in your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub coloring()
    Dim color1 As Variant, color2 As Variant, usingColor As Variant
    color1 = RGB(180, 255, 180) 'Green
    color2 = RGB(255, 255, 150) 'Yellow
    usingColor = color1

    Dim found60 As Boolean: found60 = False
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Range(Range("J2"), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, "J"))
        If found60 Then
            'Checking date is consecutive or not
            If rng.Offset(0, -2).Value - 1 = rng.Offset(-1, -2).Value Then 
                rng.EntireRow.Interior.Color = usingColor
            Else
                found60 = False
                usingColor = IIf(usingColor = color1, color2, color1)
            End If
        End If

        'We haven't found a 60 or the last series is over
        If Not found60 Then
            If rng.Value = 60 Then
                found60 = True
                rng.EntireRow.Interior.Color = usingColor
            End If
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Logic: Every time we entry a row, we check first if we had found a 60 on the last row. If we did, check the date. If the date is consecutive, we color it; if not, then we found the last date of the series. And we go back to find 60.

result: [image]

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much for taking the time to put this together. Very helpful from a learning perspective too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
Dim bOn As Boolean  ' block is on or off
Dim r As Range
Dim rDC As Range    ' range where to look for 60
Dim lBegin As Long, lEnd As Long  ' 1st and last row of the current block
Dim d As Date

Set rDC = Range("j1:j" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows)

bOn = False         ' no block has begun
For Each r In rDC
    If r.Value = 60 Then
        If Not bOn Then
            lBegin = r.Row      ' remember row where the block begins
            lEnd = 0
            d = r.Offset(0, -2).Value ' save 1st date in block
            bOn = True
        End If
    End If
    If bOn Then
        If r.Offset(1, -2) = d + 1 Then  ' check date in next row
            d = d + 1
        Else        ' end of consecutive dates
            lEnd = r.Row

 ' At this point lBegin and lEnd contains the 1st and last row of a block of consecutive dates

            If lBegin > 0 And lEnd > 0 Then
                Range(Cells(lBegin, "A"), Cells(lEnd, "J")).Copy
            End If
            lBegin = 0
            bOn = False
        End If
    End If
Next r
```